# Error of "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type can't be used to index type" when when updating value of Map

Tags: typescript

This snippet wants to assign a value to a dictionary of type key being string and value being number.

```
let dict: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();
dict["one"] = 1;
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"one"' can't be used to index type 'Map'.
>     Property 'one' does not exist on type 'Map'.Vetur(7053)

What does this error means? How do we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a Map instance is an object, the proper way to use it as a data structure is to call `.set` and `.get` to set and get values:

```
dict.set('one', 1);

console.log(dict.get('one'));
```

Maps aren't supposed to have arbitrary key-value pairs *on the instance* like you're doing, hence the TS error.

Also, TS can infer the type of the Map just fine from the expression on the right - no need for an explicit annotation. Also, unless you're planning on reassigning the Map (which is generally a pretty odd thing to want to do), it should be declared with `const`:

```
const dict = new Map<string, number>();
```